# Cant assign value to object of interface

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an interface to describe to format the informations about an image, especially some informations about image recognizitions from another atrificial intelligence software in the interface Confidence:

```
export interface Image {
    id: number;
    width?: number;
    height?: number;
    name: string;
    pfad: string;
    dateityp: string;
    ressource?: string;
    confidences?: Confidence[];
}

interface Confidence{
    class: string;
    confidence: number;
    version?: string;
    rectLeft: number;
    rectTop?: number;
    rectWidth?: number;
    rectHeight?: number;
}
```

And i have another interface, which describes the positions which a rectangle has in a canvas element:

```
export interface Rectangle {
    left: number;
    top: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
```

What i want to do is, to copy the values rectLeft, rectTop, rectWidth and rectHeight from the array of confidences to another array which contains rectangles. This is the code i tried:

```
rectangles: Rectangle[];
...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.restClient.getImageDetail(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(data => {
      data.confidences.forEach(confidence => {
        this.rectangles.push({
          left: confidence.rectLeft,
          top: confidence.rectTop,
          width: confidence.rectWidth,
          height: confidence.rectHeight
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

**The Problem**

The array of Rectangles contains after the right number of Rectangle elements, but all elements are empty, like this:

```
{left: undefined, top: undefined, width: undefined, height: undefined}
```

Then i checked the confidence inside the foreach. They're always filled with the correct values, like this - console.log(confidence):

```
class: "person"
confidence: "0.99194294"
rectheight: "0.8149626851081848"
rectleft: "0.27558863908052444"
recttop: "0.14479824900627136"
rectwidth: "0.23194609582424164"
version: "2.0.4"
```

So far so good, but if i log the value of an attribute of the confidence (e.g. console.log(confidence.rectLeft)) then the console only shows "undefined". It seems like there is a problem with the rectLeft, rectTop, rectWidth and rectHeight from Confidence, because the three other attributes (class, confidence, version) can be logged as expected.

**What i tried**

- set values manually like `left: 0.5,` works without problems
- type assertion like `left: confidence.rectLeft as number` makes no difference
- generate a `let rectangle: Rectangle = {..values..}` and push this in the array doesnt works either

I am pretty new to Typescript and Angular, i hope someone can help me.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using `as number`, try to use `+` to transform your string to a  number.   Don't forget to export your Confidence interface.

Answer (score 3):

Check for `null` values.

```
if(data && data.confidences) {
  .... write your forEach logic here
 }
```

As i can see the response values `string` where you mentioned in the interface it as `number`. Change the interface.

```
interface Confidence{
class: string;
confidence: number;
version?: string;
rectLeft: string;
rectTop?: string;
rectWidth?: string;
rectHeight?: string;
```

}

Comment: I have changed these two Parts, now the value isnt undefined anymore, but NaN. That is what a rectangle element looks like in console: `{left: NaN, top: NaN, width: NaN, height: NaN}`

Answer (score 0):

Since Rectangle Class properties are type of `number` and you are feeding `string` values to them, you need to covert values to `number` **at the time of feeding**  by putting **`+`** sign before it.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.restClient.getImageDetail(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(data => {
          data.confidences.forEach(confidence => {
            this.rectangles.push({
              left: +confidence.rectLeft,
              top: +onfidence.rectTop,
              width: +confidence.rectWidth,
              height: +confidence.rectHeight
            });
          });
        });
      }
```